# linux: how to run aria2 or wget only through eth0

Tags: linux, wget, iptables

I have a computer under Linux with several network cards, for example: eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3. Is there some way to run any downloader, like aria2 or wget only through one interface, for example eth0?

Main problem: for some reason I can't use iptables =(

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `--bind-address=ADDRESS` in `wget`. As for getting the `ADDRESS`, you could play with `ifconfig <interface_name>` and extract IP alone.

Thanks to [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104200/tim) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314930/how-to-get-pppd-inet-address-from-shell-command) post, IP can be extracted using

```
ifconfig <interface_name> | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

You should get something like this;

```
wget --bind-address=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}') {URL}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a route that tells the OS to send packets from the local machine through the network interface needed.

This will force **all** traffic through that interface. I don't think it can be done on an app by app basis, but then I'm not an expert .. those hang out at serverfault.com!